# Why do some Python modules have to be "compiled"?

Tags: python, module, compilation, package, software-distribution

I've noticed that Python modules/packages come in two sorts. Some are just pure Python scripts and can simply be copied and pasted to the Python directory. Others however require, and I think these are usually wrappers for or based on C/C++ code, that the code is "built" and/or "compiled" with setup.py to produce a set of new files.

My questions is about the second type of module/package. Why is it that they have to be compiled, is there a particular reason for it? Couldn't the distributor just provide all the files from the beginning?

The reason I ask is because I wish to distribute such C++ based packages as part of my own packages, so that the user don't have to worry about installing dependencies on their own, and not having to worry about compiling, etc. I've always wondered why module distributors don't just include the dependencies instead of asking the user to install them themselves.

I suspect the answer might be bc those extra files have to be written in a specific way depending on what type of OS the computer is, and whether it is 32 or 64 bit. Could this mean that distributing the compiled files will work, but only if the user has the same specific OS and bit-system as the one where the files were compiled.

Anyway, curious to know the answer.

Comment: Many packages do provide binary distributions, so the answer is "yes. the distributor could just provide all of the files."

Comment: I guess you all guessed correct already ;-)  Of course there also are packages which contain precompiled binaries which then will only work on the architecture they were precompiled for.

Comment: Not sure what compiled means here? Do you mean that some python modules can be installed by `pip install package` or `python setup.py install` instead of just providing a bunch of files?

Comment: Assume you have a big scientific library that takes `10Mb` of memory. Now you write 1000 small programs that use it (1kb each). If you always put the library in the same executable you end up with `(1kb + 10Mb) * 1000 = ~100Mb` of memory used, if you don't provide the dependencies in each package you end up with `1kb * 1000  + 10 Mb= 11 Mb` of memory usage. Clearly using dependencies is superior to just always using a single self-contained archive.

Comment: Good tips here. Minmizing the size of distributions seems like a logical reason for not including dependencies (esp if theyre big). @msvalkon that's not necessarily what I mean. Sometimes with setup.py it simply copies and pastes some .py files to the Python dir. But I'm talking about those times when it also produces a bunch of new C/C++ files. My main question is if I can make setup.py produce those files on my computer, and then just distribute those files directly to the user (will they even work correctly)? Or do they have to be produced with setup.py on every computer that uses it?

Answer (score 1):

Why packages just don't include dependencies: License. You can't just add somebody else's code, compiled or not, without asking the person/company or even pay fees.

In Python, these built modules you talk about are Python Extensions. They are usually there to improve performance or access low-level functionality which is not in Python. Sometimes also to include proprietary functionality.

Comment: Or simply to access low-level stuff that you can't access via pure-python and its standard library, which need *not* be "proprietary functionality".

Comment: @Bakuriu: good point about low-level stuff. I have updated answer.

Comment: @geertjanvdk maybe I should have specified. I know about the limits of licensing, but I'm talking about open-source code whose licenses allows sharing and distributing. Good tip about a reason being adding low-level functionality though.